# Change the Header Text of Autogenerated Databound Column in RadGrid

Tags: radgrid

How can i change the Header Text of Autogenerated DataBound Columns in RADGRID. I am loading a dataset whoz columns are autogenerated (Wgt1,Wgt2,Wgt3.......). I want these Column Headers as

Wgt | abc | Wgt | edg | Wgt |....... which at the moment is coming as

Wgt1 | abc | Wgt2 | edg | Wgt3 |.......

I tried

If (TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem) Then
             For Each column1 As GridColumn In e.Item.OwnerTableView.RenderColumns
      Dim dataItem As GridDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, GridDataItem)
           If column1.HeaderText = "Wgt1" Then
              dataItem("Wgt1").Text = "Wgt"
           End If
   Next
End If

But this is changing the Column Data and not the Header Text

Comment: i got the answer<br>If TypeOf e.Item Is GridHeaderItem Then<br>
            Dim header As GridHeaderItem = DirectCast(e.Item, GridHeaderItem)<br>
            header("Wgt1").Text = "Wgt"<br>
        End If<br>

Answer (score 2):

```
    protected void RadGrid2_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
        {
            dynamic data = new[] {
                    new { ID = 1, Name ="Name1"},
                    new { ID = 2, Name = "Name2"},
                    new { ID = 3, Name = "Name3"},
                    new { ID = 4, Name = "Name4"},
                    new { ID = 5, Name = "Name5"}
                };


            RadGrid2.DataSource = data;
        }
        protected void RadGrid2_ColumnCreated(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.UniqueName == "Name")
            {
                e.Column.HeaderText = "Jayesh";
            }
        }
```

Comment: <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid2_NeedDataSource" OnColumnCreated="RadGrid2_ColumnCreated" ></telerik:RadGrid>